# Using [Redux connect] in [https://jscomplete.com/repl/]

Tags: javascript, redux

I am trying to run the code from the tutorial in

> https://codepen.io/stowball/post/a-dummy-s-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react#understanding-redux-4

on

> https://jscomplete.com/repl/

, but the execution is failing with the following error:

```
ReferenceError: connect is not defined
```

I tried using an import statement at top of the file :

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
```

But it did not help resolve the error.

Is there something wrong in my understanding of the way ***jscomplete*** works?Any explanation would help
TIA

Update : Pasting the code as requested :

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class ItemList extends React.Component {



    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData('https://5826ed963900d612000138bd.mockapi.io/items');
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.hasErrored) {
            return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
        }

        if (this.props.isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading…</p>;
        }

        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.items.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        {item.label}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.items,
        hasErrored: state.itemsHasErrored,
        isLoading: state.itemsIsLoading
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchData: (url) => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url))
    };
};

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemList)

 function itemsHasErrored(bool) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_HAS_ERRORED',
        hasErrored: bool
    };
}

 function itemsIsLoading(bool) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_IS_LOADING',
        isLoading: bool
    };
}

 function itemsFetchDataSuccess(items) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
        items
    };
}

function itemsFetchData(url) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(itemsIsLoading(true));

        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }

                dispatch(itemsIsLoading(false));

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((items) => dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(items)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(itemsHasErrored(true)));
    };
}

 function itemsHasErrored(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_HAS_ERRORED':
            return action.hasErrored;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function itemsIsLoading(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_IS_LOADING':
            return action.isLoading;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

 function items(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.items;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

combineReducers({
    items,
    itemsHasErrored,
    itemsIsLoading
});

function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
}

const store = configureStore(); // You can also pass in an initialState here

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ItemList />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);


ReactDOM.render(<ItemList/>,mountNode)
```

Comment: can you provide the full code and error either as part of the question or as a jsFiddle ? (https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to a few issues. First, you need to setup Babel transpiler and its configuration for react in order to process ES6 `import` statements.

Seems like jscomplete.com (and jsFiddle) does not completely support this.

There are a few issues in the code such as referring to undeclared variables (eg: mountNode) but the main issue is that jsComplete.com not understanding the import statements.

You will have better luck running this code in a computer with VS Code or a similar editor.

Look in to **[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#create-react-app-)** which solves all of these development setup things for you when developing react applications.